Shared subscriptions and reordering due to consumer unavailable
I was reading about message brokers and that the ordering of messages can be important in certain situations and when the approach to deliver messages to multiple consumers is a shared subscription/load balancing approach (i.e. if we have 2 consumers (c1, c2), message m1 is delivered to c1, m2 to c2, m3 to c1, m4 to c2, m5 to m1 etc) if a message is not acknowledged then it is delivered to another consumer.
In this case if c1 does not acknowledge m3 while c2 is processing m4 then the broker will re-deliver m3 to c2 which now means that the sequence of processing for c2 now becomes m2,m4, m3, m5 i.e. m3 is processed after m4.
The solution mentioned is to use a separate queue per consumer but I don't understand it.
Does this mean a separate topic per consumer? If so then if the messages have some kind of ordering dependency wouldn't that mean that again m3 would be processed later than m4?  Or is the meaning of separate queue different message brokers per consumer?
